# Add Skew to Distribution without Changing mean or variance

Tags: density-function

How can I change the Skew of a PDF without changing the Mean or Variance?   And more generally, how can I change the Nth moment without changing any of the lower moments?

Vielen Dank im Voraus !

Comment: It depends on your measure of skew, but if you are using a scale-free and location-free measure of [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Definition) then change your distribution to give the skewness you want and then rescale and relocate to get back the original mean and variance

Comment: By Skew I simply mean the 3rd moment, which I believe is well defined.   Yes, I realize I can ex-post facto rescale and relocate, but I'm hoping for something more elegant.